# SharePoint List and calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to have a calculated field in a list that populates with the created by users manager?  Something like [Me].Manager.  I would like to retrieve the users properties and show them in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible out of the box. You can do it via code by using Event handlers.

Comment: That is what I though.  Is there a way to set a filter(view) on a list that shows a manager his direct reports where his direct reports are the created by field.